# Magnetic field lines

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

[image: diagram]
Is the arrow that is started (*)  incorrect in the top diagram (of the flat circle  )

Comment: The starred arrow looks OK.  The small loop on the right hand side seems to be in the wrong direction.  All of the field lines should be the same direction (upwards) inside the loop.

Comment: Close: The loop on the right has arrows in BOTH directions-so it just can't work.

Comment: On the contrary, the loop of the magnetic field on the right is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's correct. Current direction is clockwise, so we can detect that direction of current towards to us. Using right hand rule we determine clockwise direction of magnetic lines.
P.S. Sorry for my English